# Which is faster, doing float subtraction twice or doing float subtraction once, storing the result, and then using the stored result?

Tags: objective-c, performance

I have a piece of code in my program that will need to execute as fast as possible.  I have two doubles that I need to subtract in it, and I need to use the result of that subtraction twice in this piece of code.  Would storing the result in a variable and using the variable twice be faster, or would it be faster to just do the subtraction twice.  Here's what I mean in pseudocode, where x and y are doubles:

Should I do this:

```
double difference = x - y;
if(difference >= 10.0)
    return 0;
else
    return tan(difference);
```

Or this:

```
if((x-y) >= 10.0)
    return 0;
else
    return tan(x-y);
```

Bonus points if you can tell me whether > compare is significantly faster than >= compare.  It's unlikely x-y will ever be exactly 10.0, so I could go with just > if that would be faster.  This is in Objective-C for an iPhone app. Thanks.

Comment: I seriously doubt this kind of thing will have any noticable impact on your app's performance. If you're *really* worried about it, put a profiler on it and do a test. You should prefer legible code over worrying about this kind of miniscule performance issue.

Comment: What you are considering is Premature Optimization, don't do it. Unless you are doing millions just do the simplest most clear thing: re-calculate. Later use instruments to determine what is a performance problem.

Comment: Either one of them is faster than wasting time and bandwidth asking this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about splitting hairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good chances are that the optimizer will "see" what you are doing, and optimize the second code snippet to match the first code snippet. This optimization technique is called [*Common Subexpression Elimination*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination).

Moreover, the optimizer would very likely eliminate the `difference` variable altogether, using the value from the register in the call of `tan`.

In the absence of optimization the answer depends on the mixture of `x`s and `y`s: if a significant portion is such that `tan` is not called, the second snippet would be slightly faster. If most of the pairs are such that you call `tan`, the performance would be dominated by the call of `tan`, which significantly slower than a single subtraction or a single instruction to store a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your code on [RAM computational model](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBA77/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK/NODE12.HTM) on which execution time is simply the count of primitive operations . The primitive operations for this model are:

> - Assigning a value to a variable
> - Calling a method
> - Performing arithmetic operations
> - Comparing two numbers
> - Indexing into an array
> - Returning from a method

Now analyze your both codes on this basis. For your first code number of primitive operations are

```
double difference = x - y;  --------> 2
if(difference >= 10.0)      --------> 1
    return 0;               --------> 1
else
    return tan(difference); --------> 2 + p (primitive operations in tan function)
```

`6+p`.
In second code

```
 if((x-y) >= 10.0)          --------> 2
    return 0;               --------> 1
else
    return tan(x-y);        --------> 3 + p
```

number of primitive operations are `6+p`.

The performance of both code would be same.

Comment: Yeah, we used to do that on assembly language programs in the '70s but you are missing compiler optimizations and the execution mix of the two branches plus how and where x & y were assigned their values--and many other variables.

Comment: @Zaph; But most of these optimization techniques are based on the RAM computational model (RAMCM). I do not think the RAMCM results differ much with the result obtained by optimizer.

Comment: In actuality, the assembly code produced by both is identical compiles with option -Ofast.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
 1. Memory references are slow.
 2. The compiler is smart.